# Is there any option to read the total project execution time through groovy

Tags: datetime, groovy, soapui

Currently I like to calculate the total time taken for my soap ui automation project using groovy. I tried the following approach but it doesn't work:

```
Date startTime= new Date()
Date EndTime= new Date()
```

But i unable to compare the dates since it is taking the data types as string "Sat May 18 23:54:29 IST 2019" and I am unable to find the difference.

Comment: you could use `System.currentTimeMillis()` function that returns time in milliseconds. And it's easy to convert `string.toLong()` and calculate difference in millis...

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need to convert the date to string and again string to date for comparison

Comment: Ok, if you need to work with date (however I can't understand why ) then use `prop = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')` and later `Date parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'  ,prop)`

Comment: Thanks dagget!! for helping me to parse the date from string and it is working fine but little modification done for formatting the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In groovy you can use the [`TimeCategory`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) utility to subtract your dates, and get a [`TimeDuration`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeDuration.html) object representing the difference. From this object you can inspect all sort of structured time/duration information.

Also, if you have a date in a `String` representation you can parse it into a `Date` using `Date.parse` passing as a parameter the format of the string and the string representation itself.

The following is a working demo of all this:

```
import groovy.time.*

def startTimeString = "Sat May 18 00:00:00 IST 2019"
def startTime = Date.parse("E MMM dd H:m:s z yyyy", startTimeString)
def endTime = new Date()

use (TimeCategory) {
    TimeDuration duration = endTime - startTime
    println "[${startTimeString}] was [${duration}] ago"
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/groovy/so/a56204221)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Macro thanks for your response, but I am also trying this approach but the issue in soap UI I need to set the start time into project property and again I need to retrieve the property value but it will be stored as string so comparison is not working..hope you understand my issue

Comment: I just edited the answer to include the conversion of a date from a `String` representation into a `Date` and ultimately using it to compute the desired duration

Comment: Thanks a lot Marco , really it is giving accurate comparison , i am accepting this ..